# SQL noob trying to do update query with join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I’m trying to run an update query which I’ll run daily, unfortuntately I suck at SQL and have no clue what to do with the join functions. I keep getting invalid group error. I took the table names out

Managed to narrow down the issue (this is in SQLYog btw)

```
UPDATE CMCDAR

SET cmcdar.effective_exposure_in_global_currency = (mcdar.A_Rbalance - SUM(CASE 
WHEN eps.fk_account_id = '90059' AND eps.sent_to_erp = '0' THEN (eps.transaction_amount) ELSE 0 END))

FROM eps

JOIN cmcdar ON eps.fk_customer_map_id = cmcdar.fk_customer_map_id

JOIN mcdar ON eps.fk_customer_map_id = mcdar.fk_customer_map_id

JOIN mcar ON eps.fk_customer_map_id = mcar.pk_customer_map_id

WHERE cmcdar.is_deleted = 0

AND mcar.is_deleted = 0

AND mcdar.is_deleted = 0

GROUP BY eps.fk_customer_map_id;

without Group by it returns it all as one bi
```

g row, with group by it fails. Interestingly with + rather than - in the sum it seems to seperate it even without group by. Any workarounds for group by?

Comment: Isn’t that semicolon at line 9 the problem?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response - nope thats just me being an idiot while typing it up in here

Comment: The update syntax is quite database-specific. Please tag your querstion with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: what database are you using some support joins in differentways

Comment: Pro tip: start your UPDATE query out as a SELECT FROM and do all your joins and stuff. Then it should leave you free to wonder about the SET operation alone afterward.

Comment: since user has mentioned this is made with SQLyog - the RDBMS must be MySQL because SQLyog is a GUI tool for the RDBMS MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off - see here:[SQL Update with a Join](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/)

```
UPDATE 
    t1
SET 
    t1.c1 = t2.c2,
    t1.c2 = expression,
    ...   
FROM 
    t1
    [INNER | LEFT] JOIN t2 ON join_predicate
WHERE 
    where_predicate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume move the join into from clause.

```
UPDATE cmcdar

SET effective_exposure_in_global_currency = (mcdar.A_Rbalance - SUM(CASE WHEN eps.fk_account_id = 
'90059' AND eps.sent_to_erp = '0' THEN (eps.transaction_amount) ELSE 0 END))

from cmcdar
JOIN eps ON cmcdar.fk_customer_map_id = eps.fk_customer_map_id
JOIN mcar ON cmcdar.fk_customer_map_id = mcar.pk_customer_map_id
JOIN mcdar ON cmcdar.fk_customer_map_id = mcdar.fk_customer_map_id

WHERE cmcdar.is_deleted = 0
AND cmcdar.fk_customer_map_id = eps.fk_customer_map_id
AND mcar.is_deleted = 0
AND mcdar.is_deleted = 0
AND cmcdar.fk_account_id = '90059'
AND mcdar.fk_account_id = '90059';
```